# How to login a webpage programatically using a hyperlink or button in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

First of all I am new to asp.net/javascript/html (and even programming). I have found similar threads, but none of them helped me solve this task.

I would like to
1. create a link to the login page of a website and open the page in a new tab
2. then on this new page fill the user id and the password elements
3. log in with the user data.

I tried with a hyperlink, but could not find out how to run a javascript function from within an `<a>` tag when the user clicks on the link.
Then I tried to use a button, which opens a new instance of Internet Explorer, but can not figure out how to make connection with (or how to refer to) the user id and password elements on the login page.

User id element:

```
<input name="userid" tabIndex="1" id="userid" type="text" size="16"/>
```

Password element:

```
<input name="password" tabIndex="2" type="password" size="16"/>
```

Logon button element:

```
<input tabIndex="3" type="submit" value="Logon"/>
```

Thank you very much for any help!
Regards!

Comment: Try to search in google first...more than one solution available for login.

Comment: This was my first action of course. But after experimenting with many code snippets without a result, decided to open a thread.

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-User-Login-Form-example-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/how-to-create-simple-login-form-using.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Maybe I have not described the question precisely. There is an existing login page (with the above mentioned elements), and I'd like to log in automatically with a given and working userid and password from a page I am about to create.

Comment: Sorry, it's an off-topic but I gotta ask why do you use Internet Explorer?

Comment: The page I would like to log in runs only in IE. It was developed for internal use by my company and didn't have resources to optimize for different browsers, I guess.